# GUI window in Python (PyQT) flashing and closing down immediately?

Tags: python, pyqt

I am new to PyQT and I have just started learning about it through this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JBME1ZyHiP8

When I ran the code on my Ubuntu 14.04

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui # Always have these two imports

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = QtGui.QWidget()
window.setGeometry(50,50,500,300)
window.setWindowTitle("PyQt start")

window.show()
```

The window crated just flashes and closes down. How do I get the window 
to stay so that I can interact with it? The code in the Youtube video 
above demonstrated it on a Windows platform. Do I have to append anything Ubuntu specific to my code?

Comment: Why the negative vote? This is very specific and a concrete programming question!

Comment: do you get error message ?

Comment: this code works for me on Linux Mint 17 (based on Ubuntu 14)

Comment: @ furas no I dont get an error message.

Comment: @furas The program just exits without saying anything.

Comment: do you run it in console/terminal `python script.py` ?

Comment: @ furas Yes. that's exactly how I ran it. Should I run it another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't running the app, add this line to the end:

```
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

From the [relevant documentation](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qapplication.html#exec):

> int QApplication.exec_ ()
>
> Enters the main event loop and waits until exit() is called, then returns the value that was set to exit() (which is 0 if exit() is called via quit()).
>
> It is necessary to call this function to start event handling. The main event loop receives events from the window system and dispatches these to the application widgets.
>
> Generally, no user interaction can take place before calling exec(). As a special case, modal widgets like QMessageBox can be used before calling exec(), because modal widgets call exec() to start a local event loop.

Comment: Perfect that worked! Thank you! Why was that not needed on the windows version?

Comment: It _is_ needed on Windows too.

Comment: Hmm.. Well in the youtube video I linked above, the command you mentioned was not used. I was wondering why that was. Anyway thanks again for your help.

Comment: @smilingbuddha If you run it from a non-standard python terminal (like IPython or Spyder or something along those lines) then `app.exec_()` may have already been called for you.

Comment: @three_pineapples. PyQt and PySide use an input-hook to simulate event-processing in a python interactive session, so it's never necessary to call `exec_()`. See: [Using PyQt4 from the Python Shell](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/python_shell.html)